How can I disassemble a Broyhill Torren oak footboard?
I removed screws but the footboard posts will not pull apart.  Tried mallet.  Still will not separate. I want to make the footboard smaller so it will fit in car to take to the dump.  Input on how to separate this appreciated.

Take picture, post on craigslist or similar as free at curbside, set at curbside, don't worry about dump or fitting in car. Or use a bigger hammer; or throw it out the window since you're taking it to the dump, hoping the impact with the ground will break it down; or take a saw to it. If you [edit] a picture into this post some more detailed suggestions might be possible, but those all work pretty generally.

Pictures will help.  Quite often wood to wood joints will have screws plus glue, unless made to be taken apart.  If decent looking, try leaving it by the end of the driveway for someone to pick up.

Do you not own a saw of any kind?
